# Does Firefox not support KDE's Global Menu?

Tags: firefox, kde, plasma, kde5, globalmenu

Is this true that Firefox doesn't export it's menu to be used by applets like Global Menu on KDE Plasma? I am in denial because literally every GTK app supports it but Firefox doesn't. Heck, even Java apps like IntelliJ IDEA support it.

Comment: @guiverc I have installed it using the already available apt repository on Ubuntu. The package name is `firefox` and the OS is Ubuntu 20.04.